# asp.net mvc2 - update list of objects

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-2, object

I want to display list of objects from database, and on the same page have option to edit them. When submitting, I'd like to submit changes to all of them.
I found this link: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx but there is no description how to handle posted data in controller.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in you controller to catch the post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourFunction()
{
//some foo
}
```

Just as the httppost attribute in mvc you also can use the httpget attribute to catch a get action in your controller. Then the controller can do whatever you want to do with it.
I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need but i hope it helps.